# Terminal command to kick selected users off my network

Tags: terminal, network, wifi

There are lots of ports in my small office but sometimes I want to kick out people who are accessing internet instead of doing their job. With `arp -a` i can look for all of the connected users. But how to kick them off a network. Please don't tell me Router's conf. I want to do this via terminal itself. There are ways to do that, i saw my friend doing that.

Comment: Not that we aren't willing to help you, but at the same time, we ask that you exhaust your resources prior to posting, and then tell us what you already tried. In other words: if you know that your friend knows how to do it...why not ask your friend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless your desktop is the central proxy server you *will* have to go through the router. Just because you can see other machines with arp doesn't mean you can do anything with them.

Kicking them off the network via the router will usually be total - does the office staff depend on the network do do their jobs?

A better way is running your own DNS server. You can then simply redirect any time-sucking service somewhere else in a manner that makes it look like the site is temporarily down, like this:

```
*.facebook.com IN A 192.168.1.252
```

192.168.1.252 runs an Apache vhost site named `facebook.com`, it serves up a clone of the FB maintenance page for any URL.

It will take a very network-savvy user to figure it out, and you won't be the demon boss (at least not right away). Turn it on and off regularly to maintain the illusion that it's the other service.

Or for more fun: [Upside-Down-Ternet](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html).

Comment: 192.168.1.252 is a private address, not accessible from 'the outside world'. If you see a facebook maintenance joke page, it's being generated in your own building. (but I do like your upside-down ternet; I've been promising myself for years to try that one day;-)

Comment: Although I like your idea of using a DNS server with a vhost, it's a little much for the average user. Routers usually have some form of access control that will block traffic during specific times which would be far easier and just as effective to implement. If you're going to be the draconian boss, wear the shoes and take the heat.

Answer (score 5):

## KickThemOut

> Kick devices off your network by performing an ARP Spoof attack.

You can use [KickThemOut](https://github.com/k4m4/kickthemout). It’s a tool I recently developed which does exactly that — it kicks devices off your Local Area Network.

[image: KickThemOut]

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

Admins used to be able to block mac addresses at the router, but now pervasive tools for mac address spoofing allow users to easily overcome blacklists or mimic trusted computers.

If it is your own network and you do not recognize a computer attached to it, and you want them to go away, and have no way of contacting them, you can use the Low Orbit Ion Cannon (loic) to launch a denial of service attack on the unwelcome guest computer and overwhelm it with traffic. Currently denial of service attacks are among the few one-on-one methods of defending your network from a computer that has gained access without permission. Before 2015 this was inadvisable, but these days, cyberwar is upon us, so, use it with care, only in self defense and don't "lock on" to targets outside of your local network.

There are versions of the LOIC in most app stores. It is easy to use. Enter the ip address of the target, write them a nice note, lock on, and fire away until they crash off (or fire back). The original project is on sourceforge here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/loic/

If you'd like to learn more about offensive network security, check out Kali Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Type in "arp -a" to see who is on the wifi. If you have their password, you can kick them off through coding. Thanks!

Comment: This is so incorrect.  That command only lists the IP to Hardware address list that the interface knows about.  If you have people on your WiFi that you have never been in contact with, it won't show up in the ARP table.

Answer (score -1):

you can use a program called netcut. this will help you more.

Answer (score -2):

Get in CMD and writte:
net view (ENTER)
This command will show you all possible devices connected.
After that writte: SHUTDOWN/"the name of device that you want kick"
others commands:
Shutdown -s  Switch off the device
Shutdown -r  Reset the device
Shutdown -?  it shows you all other commands you can use.

Comment: You described a windows command. We are on a Apple related Stack Exhange. So how does this help the OP?